# Community builder footer

Tags: community, napili

Adding footer to the napili template

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom "> Footer content</div>
```

is overlapping with some of the content on smaller devices.

I tried to achieve using SLDS but I'm unable to position it at the bottom of the page.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The builder has a footer area .You can drop a Richtext there .

Comment: Please add more info on how you are doing this ?Is it a lightning component?

Comment: Yes Sir, It is a lightning component, updated my question. I did drop the component on to the footer area. I tried doing this way too https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/project/workshop-lightning-design-system-visualforce/slds-vf-10-footer but footer isn't fixed.

Comment: You can use SLDS Align Utility .Not sure why you have used navbar there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SLDS Align Utility](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/utilities/alignment/) to place the Text in center .

```
<div class="slds-align--absolute-center">This content will be positioned in the absolute center of its container</div>
```

Update :

I saw that the builder keeps you within the container which means you will have to write some custom styling inside your component like below

```
<div class="slds-align--absolute-center footerstyle">This content will be positioned in the absolute center of its container</div>
```

The Style.CSS inside the component is as below

```
.THIS {
}

.THIS.footerstyle {
   position:absolute;
   bottom: -500px;
   width:100%;
}
```

[image]

Using the builder I dropped a component like below

[image]

Comment: Mohith, my problem is I'm unable to fix it at the bottom of the page. https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/project/workshop-lightning-design-system-visualforce/slds-vf-10-footer If I use this the footer goes up if there is no content on the page. If I use bootstrap navbar-fixed footer is overlapping with the content in the smaller devices.

Comment: Can you please screenshot and show where exactly you want .I feel like its CSS issue and we just need to get right CSS

Comment: You can add some styling in your lightning component itself to force to it bottom center