# Specify (fallback) font stack in Community page

Tags: css, community-builder

How can I specify "sans-serif" as the fallback font in the font stack for a Community page?

The template is based on the Napali theme and uses a custom font. For some users, the custom font does not load and they instead see Times New Roman. I would like to specify that they see any other *san-serif* font in those cases.

Setting the font stack in the body did not help, with or without `!important`.

```
body {
  font-family: "Colfax", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

The only thing that I've been able to make work is to select elements at a very high specificity and set the font stack there. This is not very sustainable, though, as I keep finding items that are still falling back to serif fonts.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Colfax", Arial, sans-serif;
  src: url('/sfsites/c/resource/ColfaxRegular/Colfax-Regular.otf') format('otf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Colfax-Medium", Arial, sans-serif;
  src: url('/sfsites/c/resource/ColfaxMedium/Colfax-Medium.otf') format('otf');
}

body, .profileName, .uiMenuItem a, .uiOutputText {
  font-family: "Colfax", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.forceCommunityGlobalNavigation *, .forceCommunityGlobalNavigation button, .forceCommunityGlobalNavigation button:focus, .forceCommunityGlobalNavigation button[disabled], .forceCommunityGlobalNavigation button:hover, .forceCommunityGlobalNavigation a:focus, .forceCommunityGlobalNavigation a:hover {
  font-family: "Colfax", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.forceCommunityGlobalNavigation .slds-list__item a, .forceCommunityGlobalNavigation .slds-list__item button, .uiButton {
  font-family: "Colfax", Arial, sans-serif !important;
}

.forceCommunityHeadline .headlineTitleText {
  font-family: "Colfax", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Check if answer in this similar [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204695/custom-fonts-not-working) can help

Comment: No, it's not similar. This question is about specifying fallback font for the community page style definition.

Comment: Yea the very high level of specificity has been a problem of Salesforce for a long while. I wish I had an answer for you but I can only say that I feel your pain.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it at the "html" level - does that work?

```
body, html {
   font-family: "Colfax", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I can see that this definition comes over to page. Yet it gets overridden by other css - https://i.imgur.com/UtFQiMZ.png

Comment: Try adding !important
and/or, add button, input, optgroup, select, and textarea to the style entry