# B2B Template (LWR) - Custom Fonts

Tags: b2b-commerce, lwr, font, b2b

It is possible to use custom fonts on B2B using LWR Template?

My current configuration:

```
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'myFirstFont';
    /* Replace myFont with your resource name */
    src: url('{ basePath }/s/sfsites/c/resource/CoffeeFonts/YanoneKaffeesatz-VariableFont_wght.ttf') format('ttf');
  }

  :root {
  /** set the font for all root/body text **/
  --dxp-g-root-font-family: 'myFirstFont', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  
  /** set the font for headings **/
  --dxp-g-heading-font-family: 'myFirstFont', Times, serif;
  }
</style>
```

Static Resource:
[image]

But still not working.

Comment: Do the different URL paths in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204695/custom-fonts-not-working) post help at all? Specifically it looks like you might need to remove the '/s' at the start of the URL

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the builder. And in the site font option choose custom font and fill there MyFirstFont
[image]